# Browser caching after login/logout

Tags: caching, last-modified, http-status-code-304, if-modified-since

I've got a site with a basic login/logout system.

When I display pages I do a check to see when the page was last modified and if the browser has sent an if modified since header. **If it hasn't been modified** I send a `304` header and exit.

This obviously loads the page alot quicker and means less memory and processing power for me as I don't have to build the pages content.

However, I find that if a user logs in and then views an un-modified page he still sees the "sign in" button, the same is true if he logs out and views an un-modified page, he'll see the option to `logout`.

This seems like it would be a common occurence for anybody wishing to use `304` not modified headers, yet i'm struggling to find any discussion on how to solve it.

Any help would be much appreciated (I realise I haven't given much info but i'm not sure what else to say it's quite self explanatory)

Comment: From that point of view, a page for both a guest and a logged in are always different (in the header).  You could work with iframes or javascript updating relevant content on your page.